# Image high resolution not resizing fit to div

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I found many topics but I still have yet to find solution for my issue. When using image src from lorempixel, my code works well but when using image local (4000x3000), it not resizing to fit the div. Hope anyone can help me.

**I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1**

**HTML**

```
<section class="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-list">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/thumb-1.jpg" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/598/386/" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/598/386/" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/598/386/" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/598/386/" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="portfolio-box">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/598/386/" alt="Portfolio item">
                </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- end portfolio-list -->
</section>  <!-- end portfolio -->
```

**CSS**

```
.portfolio-list{
    background-color: #cccccc;

    li{
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mbsb16m/

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the images immediate parent elements width and height. Then you can set the image to width:100%: height:auto;

```
.portfolio-box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.portfolio-box img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/donnellyjoe/2mbsb16m/2/

Comment: Why I couldn't set height auto in the parents?

Comment: You can, but if you float them or have them display:inline-block you will have some layout issues.